# webdriver-manager update getting failed while downloading GeckoDriver

Tags: node.js, protractor

I am new to Protractor. While updating Web Driver Manager in installation step, i am facing the below issue. As you can see while downloading Gecko driver the command is getting failed. Can any one please help me on the same??

[image]

Comment: Delete the folder `C:\Users\Lipsa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mouldes\......\webdriver-manager\selenium` manually and run webdriver-manager update again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gecko driver is up to date, according to this exception.